# Writing an Instance of Functor for a Type-Synonym and Being Confused

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement a generic ring-like thing and apply it to a music data structure described by Paul Hudak in the book *The Haskell School of Music.* Naturally there's lots of Semigroup/Monoid shenanigans that are omitted, but I have the following relevant code:

```
newtype Duo     a b     = Duo     {duo1     :: a} -- A ring-like structure

data Song a =
       Primitive a
     | Song a :+: Song a             -- Composing Music Sequentially
     | Song a :=: Song a deriving Eq -- Composing Music Concurrently (in parallel)

instance Functor Song where
     fmap f (x :+: y)     = fmap f x :+: fmap f y
     fmap f (x :=: y)     = fmap f x :=: fmap f y
     fmap f (Primitive x) = Primitive $ f x

newtype Concurrent a = Concurrent {fromConcurrent :: Song a} deriving (Show)
newtype Sequential a = Sequential {fromSequential :: Song a} deriving (Show)

type Music a = Duo (Maybe (Concurrent a)) (Maybe (Sequential a))
```

I'm attempting to write an instance of Functor for Music, as Duo doesn't have a Functor I thought this wouldn't be a problem.

I wrote the following implementation:

```
instance Functor Music where
     fmap :: (a -> b) -> Music a -> Music b
     fmap f = Duo . fmap (fmap f . fromConcurrent) . duo1
```

But I get the following error:

> ```
> • The type synonym ‘Music’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none
> • In the instance declaration for ‘Functor Music’
> | 167 | instance Functor Music where
> |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Perhaps the problem is just that I'm essentially writing a Functor for only a Subset of Duo, maybe this can only work if I make music a *newtype* instead of just a type synonym. I'm really hoping to avoid that on account of the already egregious number of wrappers going on in this code, I'd really hate to add another. Maybe you all can think of a way to implement a functor for Duo that makes sense, and makes this all work?

One thing I really don't understand is why it let's me make an instance for show:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Music a) where
     show (Duo Nothing)               = "Silence"
     show (Duo (Just (Concurrent x))) = show x
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `Concurrent`, `Sequential`, and `Music` to exist at all? The `:+:` and `:=:` constructors of `Song` look like they already cover the ability to create sequential and concurrent pieces of music.

Comment: Related question: what is a ring? There's an algebraic structure in math with that name, but that concept doesn't seem super related to the rest of the question; and from a quick Google it doesn't seem to be musical jargon.

Comment: You don't need to know what a ring is to answer my question, but I wrote that anyways for god knows what reason. But I am referring to the mathematical structure, in this case, Music is what has been called a "Presemiring," two operations, both monoids (Parallel and Sequential composition), exist on the "set" Music, with the property that: a :+: (b :=: c) === (a :+: b) :=: (a :+: c) and (a :=: b) :+: c === (a :+: c) :=: (b :+: c). Where === is "morally equals." Because of the fancy monoids and music things, I can invoke general operations on Presemirings (which I admittedly have yet to find)

Comment: Oh and the idea was I also should be able to throw in existing monoids into this structure, so Duo (Sum a) (Product a) with the operations <> and >< is also a ring, so is Duo Any All, etc

Comment: I should admit though this possibly isn't the best way to structure this, I just mean "there are reasons." Not necessarily good ones. Just reasons.

Comment: You can declare an instance for a fully applied type synonym, but you cannot make an instance for the type synonym **itself**. For example with `type Option a = Maybe a`, it's fine to do `instance Show (Option a)`, because `Option a` is fully applied to all of its arguments. But `instance Functor Option` doesn't work; `Option` on it's own is just not the kind of thing that can have instances.

Comment: OTOH if type synonym had been `type Option' = Maybe` then you *could* do `instance Functor Option'`, as here `Option'` is fully applied (to all zero of its arguments). But that doesn't help `Duo`; you use the parameter in more complex ways, so you can't simply drop it.

Comment: Basically: type synonyms don't actually make real type constructors. They make a sort-of shorthand or macro. Fully applied they can be expanded to real type constructors, so *then* you can work with the result as first class types. But an unapplied type constructor isn't really a thing that the language can work with properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this kind of type-level abstraction is not allowed in Haskell. But I think you might have made some sort of conceptual error in your data type design somewhere. Expanding the types, since `Duo` has only one field, we would have:

```
Music a ~= Duo (Maybe (Concurrent a)) (Maybe (Sequential a))
        ~= Maybe (Concurrent a)
        ~= Maybe (Song a)
```

Is that really what you intended?

In the unlikely event that it is, I think I'd be very tempted to cut out the middlemen.

```
data Music a = Silence | Sound (Song a)
instance Functor Music where
    fmap f Silence = Silence
    fmap f (Sound notes) = Sound (fmap f notes)
```

If this is the intended behavior but you must keep the middlemen, `newtype` is the way forward.

In the likely event that this was not how you intended `Music` to behave, we can probably give you more/better advice, but we'd need to know more about what you intend `Duo` to mean.

Regarding your edit/comment about `Show`: in your `Show` instance, you include a type argument to `Music`. The problem with the `Functor` instance is exactly the fact that you do *not* include the argument. In the `Show` instance, because the argument is available, the compiler can simply expand the type alias, so the line

```
instance Show a => Show (Music a)
```

is identical in every way the compiler cares about to the line

```
instance Show a => Show (Duo (Maybe (Concurrent a)) (Maybe (Sequential a)))
```

In your `Functor` instance, though, the compiler cannot expand the type alias, because you have not supplied the type argument. You could imagine adding type-level lambdas to Haskell, so that you could have `instance Functor Music` mean something like

```
instance Functor (\a -> Duo (Maybe (Concurrent a)) (Maybe (Sequential a)))
```

but that has some serious problems. The naive way of adding it leads you to need to do higher-order unification during type-checking, which is undecidable.

Comment: Thank you so much! That there are reasons that wasn't what I intended, but I totally understand why you would think that, my whole project is a rather foolish undertaking, what surprises me though, is that it lets me make an instance of Show for music just fine:

Comment: @New_Caird Yes, the issue is specifically dropping the parameter `a`. The `Show` instance includes the parameter, so the compiler can simply expand the type alias; but the `Functor` instance you proposed does not, so it can't.

Comment: @New_Caird I have added a section discussing the issue a tiny bit more.